# Google Text Detection API is giving different response for same image from local and cloud

Tags: go, google-cloud-vision

I am using google text detection api, while running text detection from local machine I am getting good results while it runs through staging environment from cloud it gives bad responses, so the significant mismatch is coming in the results. Is it a GCV bug, please help me find the solution.

Comment: You need to add more info..

Comment: Hi Mark, locally(App) when I run an image to detect text, The results are like "Government of USA", when The same code deployed to google cloud, the result with the same is "vernment of US4". I am using golang vision to make Text detection request

Answer (score 1):

There could be an issue with the way you import the image or with the way you authenticated the access to the Vision API. Follow this tutorial provided by Google on [Using the Vision API with Python](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-vision-api-python/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) to get the idea of how to use the Google Cloud API and test your image there to see if there is any difference.

Other than that, Mark. F is right, this question needs more explanation, so we could understand and replicate the issue.

Comment: Hi Andrei, locally(App) when I run an image to detect text, The results are like "Government of USA", when The same code deployed to google cloud, the result with the same is "vernment of US4". I am using golang vision/v1 package to make Text detection request

Comment: It seems that the library you are using has been `DEPRECATED`. Check the [package vision](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/vision/v1) for more information. It is suggested to use the new package `cloud.google.com/go/vision/apiv1` instead. It might be the reason you see different result in the Google Cloud.